# Let V be vector space, U subspace of V,Prove that it is not possible that every vector in V\U is a scalar multiple of v from V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

i would be happy if someone would help me with something im trying to prove for my homework assignment.

**the question:**
let V be a vector space,U is a subspace of V that is not equal to  V, U$\neq${0}.
let v be a vector from V.
prove that it is not possible that every vector from V\U (from V but not from U) is a scalar multiplication of v.

I thought about splitting the prove into 2 parts:

1)if v is from U than it is easy beacuse every vector from U is still in U after multiplying it by a scalar.

2) if v is from V\U.... i am stuck here

thanks!

Comment: Hint:  suppose $\vec u\in U-{0}$.  Then, assuming $\vec v \notin U$, consider $\vec w= \vec u+\vec v$.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct that $v$ cannot belong to $U$. But there's a different way. Suppose such a $v$ exists. Then
$$
V=U\cup\langle v\rangle
$$
(where $\langle v\rangle$ denotes the subspace spanned by $v$).

It is well known that if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of a vector space, then $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace if and only if $U_1\subseteq U_2$ or $U_2\subseteq U_1$.

Comment: thank you. i like your way of thinking, but how can u know that <v> is a subspace?

Comment: @Eden It is the subspace spanned by $v$.

Answer (score 0):

you have already proved (1). For (2), let's use contradiction. If it is possible that one special vector $v_s \in V\setminus U $ is a scalar multiple of a vector $v \in V$, then from (1), we know that the special vector $v_s \in V$, which contradicts to the assumption. So you can complete your proof. You are very close to it.